# Quasinilpotent , non-compact operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $X$ is a separable Banach space and $(\epsilon_n)\downarrow 0$, can we find a quasinilpotent, non-compact operator on $X$ such that $||T^n||^{1/n}<\epsilon_n$ for all $n$? I suspect the answer is positive, but cannot come up with an example.

Comment: What is wrong with a nilpotent shift on $L^p[0,1]$? For example $(Tf)(x):=f(x+\frac{1}{2})$ if $x<\frac{1}{2}$ and $(Tf)(x)=0$ elswhere?

Comment: @AndrásBátkai: What is probably a bit more interesting is to find such an operator which is, in addition, not power-compact, and thus in particular not nilpotent. (An example would be the resolvent of a nil-potent vector-valued shift semigroup.)

Comment: @AndrásBátkai: Oh, I think we misunderstood the question. I guess, Markus asks whether such an operator exists for every separable space $X$ and every sequence $(\epsilon_n)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Argyros-Haydon space every operator is a compact perturbation of a scalar multiple of the identity, and hence every quasinilpotent operator is compact.

Comment: Just curious: is the property "quasinilpotent is compact" equivalent to Argyros-Haydon property "every operator is scalar plus compact"?

Comment: Probably not, Fedor.  Maybe there is a space with unconditional basis on which every operator is diagonal plus compact. Gowers built a space with unconditional basis on which every operator is diagonal plus strictly singular.